# Finding particular check box from the checkbox list in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

My code is as below

```
      <ListBox x:Name="lstbxRefMarket" Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderThickness="0" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkbxRefMarket" Content="{Binding Market}" CommandParameter="{Binding MarketId}" Tag="{Binding MarketId}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Checked="chkbxRefMarket_Checked" Unchecked="chkbxRefMarket_Unchecked"  Foreground="Blue"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now in code behind I need to uncheck the particular checkbox with MarketId as 8  from chkbxRefMarket list 
As you see from the code checkbox will be having CommandParameter ,Tag as MarketId

How can I find the particular checkbox with that market id in the list .

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply find the right item and set its `Checked` property. The associated CheckBox is bound to that property and will automatically be unchecked.

The code below assumes that your data item class is `MyItem`.

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> items = lstbxRefMarket.Items.OfType<MyItem>();
MyItem item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MarketId == 8);

if (item != null)
{
    item.Checked = false;
}
```